# Where can I find the folder which houses the system applications that appear when right-clicking the windows logo on windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-corruption, users, appdata

I've recently re-installed all my program files onto a new system through downloading them from the internet and installing them, while also copying the AppData folder, under Users/*computer name*/, from the old PC into the new PC's AppData folder and now the newly installed files aren't working properly and I'm getting anomalies such as when I
right click the windows logo:

[image: right-click the windows logo]

I've been fixing the broken programs by deleting essentially all traces of an application from every folder I could possibly think of and re-installing them with success. Where can I find the folder containing the tools in the screenshot, so I can remove the duplicates? Also, is there any sort of tool to repair corrupt programs, as I'm fairly certain I copied over some items in Program Data and Program Data x86 as well.

**Edit:** So, I've found the folder housing the Windows Administrative Tools, but this isn't very helpful in determining how I can remove the duplicates. Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: How exactly did you reinstall your files?  Please be extremely specific.  Instead of a comment edit your question

Comment: @Ramhound I've clarified some more, but let me know if more information is still needed

Comment: Wow.. I have never seen anyone even try this.  What happens if you create a new user and login as that user?

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your %localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX\Group2, if you see duplicates delete them from all 3 groups

Comment: @SQLTemp There were many duplicates in each Group folder and deleting them seems to have fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All of the WinX menu items are sorted under `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`with this folder having 3 sub folders, Group1, Group2 and Group3.

Open up each sub folder and delete any duplicated records and this should be fixed.